# AJAX call to PHP not working yields a blank page

Tags: ajax

We are implementing the "forget password" feature for our website.
We are usign HTML, JQquery mobile and AJAX .
we have a main file, which has the hyperlink for the forget password using the '' tag.
The password.html has form elements as below:

```
<form method ="post" id="forget" action="somefile.php" >
<h4>Enter your login email to change your password..</h4>
<label for="email" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email:</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="email" data-theme="a"  />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b" />
</div>
</form>
```

The php file validates the email and sends the response in JSON format , which we are handling through a ajax call.

The problem is after hitting on "submit" in the password.html, we are able to retreive the data from the php file(able to see in network tab of browser) but it does not display on the frontend.

The browser is navigating to the php file (which it should not) and a blank page is being displayed.

Ps: When we directly load the password.html in the browser the behaviour is absoultely fine , but when we are navigating from the main file usign the hyperlink to password.html then this problem occurs.

Comment: Please add some code so we can see your exact problem and help you diagnose it.

Comment: Read the `error_log` file.